# Trying to get tflite weights as a c variable

Tags: python, c, tensorflow, stm32, tensorflow-lite

I am using stm32 for AI, using the X Cube AI library, and i am trying to send the network weights of a given model to my microcontroller via UART.
For this purpose i need to use a python script that could get the weights of my tflite model as a c variable like it is on the stm32:
[How the model is stored on the stm32](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iS5GU.png)

[image]

I have tried conversion tools such as the `xxd -i` command or the `convert_bytes_to_c_source` function, but it always converts the whole tflite file while i only need the weigths.

Comment: Please don't put code snippets as screenshot here (but select the relevant parts and embed them as formatted inline code in your question so parts of it can be searched and referred to).

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to my problem. The X cube AI library just transforms the weights of the model from signed float to hex using the IEEE 754 standard.
We can do this by usig this webite: [https://gregstoll.com/~gregstoll/floattohex/](https://gregstoll.com/%7Egregstoll/floattohex/) (they even have a python code for it)

We can see the comparison between the first weights and the values of the network data:
here are the the first two weigths of the model in float and in hex (converted using the website method):

[The first two weights of the model in float and hex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wjl2.png)

[The weights as they are stored on the STM32](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6zBI.png)

If we compare this to the value of the weights as they are stored on the STM32 they are indeed the same values as the first 8 bytes of value.

Comment: how is it related to the UART transfer to the uC?

Comment: It is because i needed to get the weights as a variable in order to send them via uart.

Comment: how do you want to use this C code on the running uC program?

Comment: I want to send like the file via uart, is it not possible?

Comment: you want to send text .c file ?

Answer (score 0):

Simply

1. Write a function which will read this data from the UART.
2. Call it

```
ai_handle ai_network...get(void)
{
    static ai_u8 s_network_weights[6720];
    uart_read_data(s_network_weights, sizeof(s_network_weights));

    /*...*/
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your awnser but i was asking for a way to get the tflite weigths in the form of a c file on pyhton. I think i phrased my question wrong sorry.

Comment: @littleLad You cant send `.c` file to the uC via UART and use it. C is the **compiled** language and you need to compile and link your sources first using other (normal - large computer) and the program the FLASH memory. Without learning C you will struggle with uCs. Python is far not enough.